# How to compute an expensive high precision sum in python?

Tags: python, performance, math, numpy

My problem is very simple. I would like to compute the following sum.

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy.misc import comb
import math

for n in xrange(2,1000,10):
    m = 2.2*n/math.log(n)
    print sum(sum(comb(n,a) * comb(n-a,b) * (comb(a+b,a)*2**(-a-b))**m
                    for b in xrange(n+1))
               for a in xrange(1,n+1))
```

However python gives  `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply` and `nan` as the output and it is also very very slow.

Is there a clever way to do this?

Comment: For a start, get rid of the `[]`; you don't need those intermediate lists.

Comment: comb(n,a) means n!/(a!)*(n-a)!

Comment: Have you considered `cython`?

Comment: @mbatchkarov Do you think that would help?

Comment: @larsmans This doesn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: Or replace `comb` with `scipy.special.binom` and replace the two inner loops by vectorized evaluation over `a=numpy.arange(1,n+1); b=numpy.arange(n+1)`

Comment: well assuming the previously asked, first of all you dont need those list like @larsmans said, and in the second place you can compute the comb in a matrix to retrieve it later in O(1). Hope it helps.

Comment: @pv. Just replacing comb with scipy.special.binom lets the code work up to n = 502. However n = 512 or larger still fails.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why you get NaNs is you end up evaluating numbers like

```
comb(600 + 600, 600) == 3.96509646226102e+359
```

This is too large to fit into a floating point number:

```
>>> numpy.finfo(float).max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Take logarithms to avoid it:

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
from scipy.special import betaln
from scipy.misc import logsumexp
import numpy as np


def binomln(n, k):
    # Assumes binom(n, k) >= 0
    return -betaln(1 + n - k, 1 + k) - np.log(n + 1)


for n in range(2, 1000, 10):
    m = 2.2*n/np.log(n)

    a = np.arange(1, n + 1)[np.newaxis,:]
    b = np.arange(n + 1)[:,np.newaxis]

    v = (binomln(n, a) 
         + binomln(n - a, b) 
         + m*binomln(a + b, a) 
         - m*(a+b) * np.log(2))

    term = np.exp(logsumexp(v))
    print(term)
```

Comment: OK.. so this is what they call a really great answer. It's the sort of thing SO should use to advertise itself!

Comment: @Anush Yeah it's called the "Hot Network Questions" to the right. That's how I found this neat Q & A.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Memoize](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) pattern. With that, redefine comb:

```
@memoized
def newcomb(a, b):
    return comb(a, b)
```

And replace all calls to `comb` with `newcomb`. Also, for a minor improvement, remove the brackets. If you make explicit lists, you waste time constructing them. If you remove them, you're effectively using [generator expressions](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html).

**Update**:

This won't solve the `nan` issue, but does make it a lot faster.

For everyone who does not see this as being faster, are you applying the memoize decorator? On my machine, the original function takes 29.7s to go up to 200, but only 3.8s with the memoized version.

What memoize does is simply store all your invocations of `comb` in a lookup table. So if in a later iteration you're invoking `comb` with the same arguments as you had at some point in the past, it doesn't recalculate it - it simply looks it up in the lookup table.

Comment: How large an n can you do like this?  In particular, does it help with n = 512?

Comment: doesn't seem to speed it up significantly, though i thought it would

Comment: @Anush:

Not sure why it fails at 512. I modified your exponentiation to use `math.pow` and it now doesn't fail, but starts giving nans at 512. I suspect some expression is overflowing. Probably raising it to the power of m is the culprit - you may need to reformulate your expression to prevent this.

Comment: dont see how this "newcomb" is faster than "comb" ??

Comment: For everyone who does not see this as being faster, are you applying the memoize decorator? On my machine, the original function takes 29.7s to go up to 200, but only 3.8s with the memoized version.

What memoize does is simply stores all your invocations of `comb` in a lookup table. So if in a later iteration you're invoking `comb` with the same arguments as you had at some point in the past, it doesn't recalculate it - it simply looks it up in the lookup table.

Comment: @user1462309: Ah ok, i was running it correctly but i didn't notice the speed difference from just running the program with and without. yea it is quite a bit faster, but still not fast enough